# constraint satisfaction in java

Tags: java, constraint-programming

I am having a problem programming the below problem in java it is a constraint satisfaction problem:

If I have constraints like this:

1. x1 + x2 > x3
2. x2 - x4 = 2
3. x1 + x4 < x5

Each of `x1` to `x5` are in the domain `{0,1,2}`

How do I program the different combinations such that I will have a set of tuples as: `{(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0), ......}` for each constraint

that is constraint 1 for instant has domain of tuple such as `{(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,2),(2,0,1) ......}`

I need the reply in any language but preferably java please.

Comment: Haza http://maths.uncommons.org/api/org/uncommons/maths/combinatorics/CombinationGenerator.html

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps do this through the use of some helper methods from the google commons collect library. It would look something like this:

I'm assuming that the tuples (0,0,0) etc are tuples of the input to the constraint, (x0, x1, x2) for constraint1, (x2, x4) for constraint2 etc.

So, for constraint1, first we fill a list with all possible combinations:

```
    final List<int[]> allCombos = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                allCombos.add(new int[] {i, j, k});
            }
        }
    }
    for (final int[] i : allCombos) {
        System.out.println(i[0] + ", " + i[1] + ", " + i[2]);
    }
```

Next, we want to filter so we'll be left with the tuples that are allowed by constraint1:

```
    final List<int[]> constraint1 = ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.filter(allCombos, new Predicate<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable final int[] input) {
            return input[0] + input[1] > input[2];
        }
    }));

    for (final int[] i : constraint1) {
        System.out.println(i[0] + ", " + i[1] + ", " + i[2]);
    }
```

This might need a little explanation.

ImmutableList.copyOf is a method that creates a copy of a given list. To this method, we pass the result of Iterables.filter(), which takes a list (the input to be filtered), and a Predicate, which has an overridden method apply(), where you decide which element of the input list that are supposed to be part of the result list. Here, we basically just code the constraint itself, and the cases where the apply method returns true will be part of the filtered list. (I've chosen to represent the tuples as an array, you could use the filter-strategy with any tuple-representation..)

The result of the last printouts (the filtered list) will be:

```
0, 1, 0
0, 2, 0
0, 2, 1
1, 0, 0
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 1
1, 2, 2
2, 0, 0
2, 0, 1
2, 1, 0
2, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
2, 2, 0
2, 2, 1
2, 2, 2
```

I'll leave it up to you to do the same for the other constraints..

Comment: Thanks a million, its an eye opener, it will really help but in a situation whereby my number of variables in my linear equation can not be predetermined eg 1) x1 + x2 =x3,    2) x1 - x2 + x3 = x4,    3) x2 + x3 - x5 = x1 + x6.  What do you advice?

Comment: Are the constraints determined at runtime? Or are they hard-coded?

Comment: At run time pls. We want it to be able to accommodate any linear/SAT equation of any length of variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish here. Do you want an factory that will produce tables of what combinations of input would satisfy a certain criterium? Are the criteria related? Where does the criteria come from?

Comment: I didn't mean the turples must satisfy a criterium but all turples that stand the chance of satisfying it; considering other variables. You got it initially when a constraint has three variables but how can it be done dynamic such that weather tuples are '2': {0,0}, '3':{1,0,1}, '4': {1,0,1,2} etc it will be solvable.

Comment: The criteria are the constraints and the format is eg x1 + x2 =3 will have {(0,0),(0.1),(1,0),(1,0)} for all x1 and x2 in the domain of {0,1}. I will appreciate if you can help with this even though i already have a backup plan to do it in another way.

Comment: You are not answering my question, if the constraints are dynamically created, rather than hardcoded, they must be input in a certain way, and they must come from somewhere. It is no problem to use the method I've suggested for any hard-coded constraint, but once they are dynamic it becomes very different.

Comment: Okay. Constraint can be any linear equation.

Comment: Still not answering my question. Can't help you.